# Jquery and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: jquery

Attempting to disable a textbox if one of the radiobuttons is selected:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#radPerpetrator").change(function () {
            var st = this.checked;
            if (st) {
                $("#txtPerpetratorOther").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

.Net Code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radPerpetrator" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<asp:ListItem>Parent</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Guardian</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Sibling</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Relative</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Teacher</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

Other: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPerpetratorOther" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: what is the value of radio button??

Comment: When you inspect your HTML in-browser, do you see your original IDs on those elements, or has ASP altered them?

Comment: use html input instead of asp controls.

Comment: I believe ASP is altering the IDs. Any good way around this or to accommodate?

Comment: @user1422570 post the compiled html code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to identify the asp server controls from script but my workaround is to assign each control a unique class name.  Then use the class from script.  Note I had to change from 'prop' to 'attr' because of the older jquery you specified.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radPerpetrator" CssClass="radiolist" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<asp:ListItem>Parent</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Guardian</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Sibling</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Relative</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Teacher</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

Other: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPerpetratorOther" CssClass="textboxOther" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".radiolist input").change(function () {
            alert(this.defaultValue + ' changed: checked=' + this.checked);
            if (this.checked) {
                //note: one of the list items is always checked after initial one is clicked
                $('.textboxOther').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use html input instead of asp controls. It's working well.

```
<input type='radio' class='radio' name='type' value='1' />
<input type='radio' class='radio' name='type' value='2' />
<input type='radio' class='radio' name='type' value='3' /> 
<input type="text" id="txtPerpetratorOther" />

$(function () {
    $(".radio").change(function () {
        var st = this.checked;
        if (st) {
            $("#txtPerpetratorOther").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**
you put

> runat="server"

in radiobutton list that's the reason the page is reloading. so the javascript can't catch the event.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way to use jquery with ASP.Net controls?

Comment: post the html code here. then i will tell you.

Comment: @user1422570 you put runat="server" in radiobutton list that's the reason the page is reloading. so the javascript can't catch the event.

Comment: Used ClientIDMode="Static" and the id issue resolved. Not sure if the code it right that checks if a radiobutton is selected however.

Comment: That code is fine!